# Bootstrap Multiselect CSS displaying incorrectly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I have a ASP.net application that is using the bootstrap multiselect script. Unfortunately something weird is happening when I try to display it in HTML.

Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
    });
</script>
```

What it looks like in HTML:

[image]

And proof that it is all loading:
[image]

Anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Bootstrap and what version of Bootstrap Multiselect are you using?

Comment: @TiesonT. I'm using Bootstrap version 4.3.1 and I have the most recent version on their github, so 0.9.15. I'm also using jQuery version 3.3.1

Comment: Bootstrap Multiselect isn't 100% compatible with Bootstrap 4, as-is. The classes it uses to build the drop-down are from Bootstrap 3, which is why you're seeing it render the way it is.

Comment: Ok, so will moving to Bootstrap 3 solve my problem?

Comment: Well, yeah, but Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 have quite a few differences, so you're going to be updating quite a bit of markup and/or code. I would probably look for a fork that's been updated, first.